# Need info with Qt5 path on cmake

Tags: cmake, qt5

I am developing a project with Qt5 and I want to run a process inside CMake script. I need to deploy the application so I want to know the path of Qt5 libraries so I can run on CMake the windeployqt.exe and create the installer of the application. Is there any variable inside the script which has the Qt5 path?

Comment: Did you try `Qt_DIR`?

Comment: Yes but unfortunately it has the value /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5 inside cmake directory, qmake isn't there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set qt5 path with cmake find\_package on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50764721/how-to-set-qt5-path-with-cmake-find-package-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I use the following snippet in various projects:

```
# extract the Qt root dir
if (TARGET Qt5::qmake)
  get_target_property(_qt5_qmake_path Qt5::qmake LOCATION)
  get_filename_component(MY_QT_BIN_DIR ${_qt5_qmake_path} DIRECTORY)
  get_filename_component(MY_QT_ROOT_DIR ${MY_QT_BIN_DIR} DIRECTORY)
endif()
```